# Then Function Running before Store Action in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So in my brands.js store I have this action which calls the API:

```
  getBrandMerchants({ commit }, id) {
    commit('setLoading', true);
    BrandService.getBrandMerchants(id)
      .then((response) => {
        commit('setBrand', formatter.deserialize(response.data.result.brand));
        commit('setMerchants', formatter.deserialize(response.data.result.merchants));
        commit('setLoading', false);
        console.log('First');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
          dispatch('alert/error', error.response, { root: true });
        } else {
          Toast.open({
            type: 'is-danger', message: error.response.data.meta.message,
          });
        }
      });
  },
```

In my components I have the following snippets:

```
...mapState('brands', ['merchants']),
```

```
...mapActions('brands', ['getBrandMerchants']),
```

When I try to run this method in my component:

```
    addMerchantsToBrandGroup(index) {
      const { id } = this.rows[index].brand;
      if (id === null) { return; }

      this.getBrandMerchants(id)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Second');
          this.rows[index].merchants = this.merchants
        });
    },
```

console results to

```
Second
First
```

How can I make it so console returns
First then Second?

```
First
Second
```

Comment: `getBrandMerchants` needs to be `async` and `await` `BrandService.getBrandMerchants`, or return its promise.

Comment: simple fix: `return BrandService.getBrandMerchants(id)...`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @deceze:

Adding async and await to:

```
  async getBrandMerchants({ commit }, id) {
    commit('setLoading', true);
    await BrandService.getBrandMerchants(id)
      .then((response) => {
        commit('setBrand', formatter.deserialize(response.data.result.brand));
        commit('setMerchants', formatter.deserialize(response.data.result.merchants));
        commit('setLoading', false);
        console.log('First');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
          dispatch('alert/error', error.response, { root: true });
        } else {
          Toast.open({
            type: 'is-danger', message: error.response.data.meta.message,
          });
        }
      });
  },
```

and

```
async addMerchantsToBrandGroup(index) {
      const { id } = this.rows[index].brand;
      if (id === null) { return; }

      await this.getBrandMerchants(id)
      console.log('Second');
      this.rows[index].merchants = this.merchants
    },
```

Solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: await is supposed to replace .then and .catch , it's either one or another. The problem is more fundamental, you need to chain promises correctly. It could be fixed by always returning a promise to chain, e.g. `return  BrandService.getBrandMerchants ... `